# Can output events be fired for dynamically created components

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-output

What I'm trying to do:

1. Create components dynamically (done)
2. Allow the dynamically created components to leverage "outputs" so that parent Components can listen for changes from the children.

Here is a Plnkr for what I'm trying do to.
Plnker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/XpDCGIwd2at9oR74lpY5?p=preview

When the user Clicks "+ Component" the following creates the component

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
let ref = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Within each child component that is added, when the user clicks the "Fire Event"

```
<span class="initiateParentAction" 
  (click)="fireEventEmitter()" [class.eventFired]="eventFired==true">Fire Output Event: {{eventFired}}</span>
```

it calls the following

```
fireEventEmitter(){
    console.log("Event Fired");
    this.parentActionReq.emit({
      action: "helloWorld"
    });
    this.eventFired = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.eventFired=false, 2000);
}
```

The parent component (in this case "App" component), is listening for these Outputs as shown here

```
<ng-container #container 
    (parentActionReq)="childActionInitiated($event)"></ng-container>
```

I have been unable to get events from Dynamically created components to register with the parent. In the Plnker, the "Received child output Event" should turn to true.

At this point, I'm thinking that due to the fact that these components are added at runtime, I need to somehow re-initialize event detection OnInit. But have made no headway.

Any suggestions, hints, guidance would be appreciated here.

I'm hesitant to go down the path of creating my own Observables, as this seems like it would be re-creating the wheel, the Output serves my purpose exactly.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Can you please update the plunker, how you got this working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, dynamically added components don't support binding to inputs or outputs. You can set and read data imperatively though.

```
ref.instance.someProp = 'someVal';
ref.instance.someOutput.subscribe(val => this.prop = val);
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll look into the the suggested alternative approach.

Comment: @Edward Günter is very fast) +1

Comment: And @yurzui usually has very high quality answers :)